# Determine the series for cos x^2

Tags: taylor-expansion

Use the series for Cos x (Taylor Series)

If you could give me help or the solution to the problem, that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Hints: Write Taylor for $\cos x$, then replace $x$ by $x^2$ in that series. Clear?

Comment: Is it $\cos(x^2)$ or $\cos(x)^2$? It's an important fact here.